# Does the SDK allow for naming files differently from DJI_000x

Tags: dji-sdk

Just wondered if anyone knew if the DJI SDK has a method available for an app to name them whatever it wants, regardless of if it's a pain to accomplish or not.

I'm actually using DroneDeploy and am trying to get confirmation on whether a feature request would be possible or not rather than it simply isn't a feature they want to implement.

When I do my plans, say three or four a day I get DJI_0001-DJI_0999 then a new MEDIA directory is created to do the next '1000'. Just wondered if it were possible to name the files, say, make the variable for the filename the Project Name then add sequential numbers to the end like 'Field 1_0001' and 'Farm House 1_0001'.

Just thought it would save me a few hours a year in file management and looking at thumbnails to find the start and finish of a flight I've completed.

No biggy if it's not possible, just want to get a definitive answer.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no as of MSDK 4.4